# Why absolute and relative positioning does not work as expected in firefox?

Tags: css, file, firefox, input, absolute

Why does not the following fiddle work properly (text disappears) only in firefox?

What I am trying to do in the below fiddle is,

I dont like browser's file upload control and I am creating CSS for it to look like a button. The file upload control is enclosed in a div and is hidden via opacity property. CSS is added to the outer div to make it look like a button.

### Markup and CSS

HTML:

```
<button id="Ctrl" class="button" type="button">Query</button>
<div id="file" class="file-label appletButton">
New File
<input id="FileInput" class="file-input" type="file" name="fileinput" multiple></div>
```

CSS

```
.file-input {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 100px 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -ms-filter:'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)';
    -moz-transform: translate(-300px, 0) scale(4);
    -o-transform: 'translate(250px, -50px) scale(1)';
}
.file-label {
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.appletButton {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8ABAFE 0%, #5788C7 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #31537F;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/6ZuPM/7/

In the above fiddle, first click on "Query" button. Then press TAB key. The "New File" text disappears. But you will still be able to invoke browse window by clicking the blue button. WHY THE TEXT DISAPPEARED?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve I have the same display on chrome and firefox (except for the gradient background you coded in mozilla style)

Comment: I am trying to hide the file upload control. And on top of that, I want to display button like CSS styles. The issue I am facing in the above example is, When I press TAB, the text on the file upload control disappears. I want the text to be there even if I TAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit tab, the browser puts focus on the file input, since that's the next thing in the tab order.

When something is focused, browsers try to scroll it into view.  So in this case the `<div class="file-label">` is scrolled however far it needs to be scrolled to bring the file input into view, which scrolls the text out of view.

Comment: and how can can I avoid this?

Comment: Make the file input not tab-focusable by setting tabindex on it accordingly?

Comment: Hello Boris. I have tried with tabindex. Its working fine in parent window. But on jquery popup window... I am unable to open file select dialog. Any idea why?

Comment: @user1853164 Not offhand, no.

Comment: Text disappearing issue can be fixed by adding "font-size=100px" to ".file-input" and have to remove "Width=100%". But font-size is not restricted to 100px. you can increase its value as per the need.

Answer (score 1):

About position:relative and position:absolute :

```
 position:relative;
```

Keeps your element in the flow of the page, you can even specify floats on it. It takes its origin in its parent.

```
 position:absolute;
```

Removes your element from the flow of the page. It takes its origin in the body element, unless it is nested in position:relative element (your example) , then the position:absolute element takes its origin in its parent.

Comment: An absolutely positioned element will sit relative to the next parent up with a `position` other than `static` (default)

Comment: thanks for precision, not sure it will be of any help to op though